# Cannot fix "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" making webrequest

Tags: c#, api, security, ssl, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to make a webrequest from a localhost project running on a Virtual Machine. The problem is I can not create a webrequest and I will receive the following error:

"**The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel**".

When I try to acces the same API im calling in my webrequest with Postman(also from my virtual machine) it does work:

**THIS DOES NOT WORK:**

Webrequest code:

```
try
            {
                ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
                       | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
                       | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
                       | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/ditto/");
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseBody);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
```

Response:

[image]

**THIS DOES WORK:**

[image]

**WHAT I'VE ALREADY TRIED:**

I've already searched for this error and all of the solutioons where to add the following lines of code:

```
 ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
                       | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
                       | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
                       | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

Hope someone can help,

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, finally!

Because the API I was trying to call was https and my own application was http, it caused the error!

Comment: How did you fix it? Please explain for others who might stumble across this question

Comment: I can call http requests, just not https requests.